# How to execute a line of code once and never again even on re-rendering and navigation

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I'm new to react. I'm stuck at a point.
This below page only loads only if the commented line of code is uncommented.
But then it is affecting the functionality of the code since everytime the page renders, it is executing. Please let me know what is wrong here, or what approach should I take to fix it. Thank you in advance.

```
 function DocumentTable() {
  const data = [{ id: "", name: "", code: "" }];
  const [documentData, setDocumentData] = useState(data);
  // window.localStorage.setItem("document", JSON.stringify(data));  //comment this line.
  let dataForDocumentTableRows = JSON.parse(
    window.localStorage.getItem("document")
  );
  const tableRows = dataForDocumentTableRows.map((info) => {
    return (
      <Tr>
        <Td>{info.id}</Td>
        <Td>{info.name}</Td>
        <Td>{info.code}</Td>
      </Tr>
    );
  });

  const addRows = (data) => {
    const totalDocuments = documentData.length;
    console.log(totalDocuments);
    data.id = totalDocuments;
    const updatedDocumentData = [...documentData];
    console.log(updatedDocumentData);

    updatedDocumentData.push(data);
    setDocumentData(updatedDocumentData);
    window.localStorage.setItem(
      "document",
      JSON.stringify(updatedDocumentData)
    );

    console.log(documentData);
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <DocumentForm func={addRows} />
      <TableContainer mt={"10vh"}>
        <Box bg={"teal"} fontSize={"30"}>
          <center>Document List </center>
        </Box>
        <Table variant="striped" colorScheme="teal" size="lg">
          <Thead>
            <Tr>
              <Th>Document ID</Th>
              <Th>Document Name</Th>
              <Th>Document Code</Th>
            </Tr>
          </Thead>
          {dataForDocumentTableRows && <Tbody>{tableRows}</Tbody>}
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default DocumentTable;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you structure it so that the setItem() is only reached if it does not exist? In other words: if (not exist) you setItem(), else you do nothing?

Comment: I didn't think of this before. Got it working. Thank you so much! @dev.AMS